# Rendered doesn't work in dataTable primefaces JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have problem with 4 ifs in my code on jsf. I have to check 3 parameteres and when it is ok show appropriate message. Why its doesn't work? In dataGrid it works in c:when

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{msg.deleted}" class="delete" rendered="#{((!advertisement.isStarted) and (!advertisement.isActive) and (!advertisement.isFinished))}"/>
<h:outputLabel value="#{msg.done}" class="done" rendered="#{((advertisement.isStarted) and (!advertisement.isActive) and (advertisementisFinished))}"/>
<h:outputLabel value="#{msg.realize}" class="realize" rendered="#{((advertisement.isStarted) and (advertisement.isActive) and (!advertisement.isFinished))}"/>
<h:outputLabel value="#{msg.open}" rendered="#{((!advertisement.isStarted) and (advertisement.isActive) and (!advertisement.isFinished))}"/>
```

All time I dont understand solution of BalusC

I have:

```
public boolean isIsActive() {
    return isActive;
}

public void setIsActive(boolean isActive) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
}

public boolean isIsStarted() {
    return isStarted;
}

public void setIsStarted(boolean isStarted) {
    this.isStarted = isStarted;
}

public boolean isIsFinished() {
    return isFinished;
}

public void setIsFinished(boolean isFinished) {
    this.isFinished = isFinished;
}
```

Comment: Yes i have in entities class isStarted, isFinished, isActive. On other side with datagrid it works.
I use it to show status of operation.

Comment: Wait wait wait, I have in entities

public boolean getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public boolean isIsStarted() {
        return isStarted;
    }

    public boolean isIsFinished() {
        return isFinished;
    }

Comment: Where is the datatable? Where is the corresponding bean? Please read [ask] and [mcve]